# Aligning figcaption and figure tags on the same line

Tags: html, css, image, tags, figure

So like the title said, I added figcaption and figure tag to give my images captions. The captions showed but each image is showing on a new line. Before I added the figure and figcation tag, I flexed them and put them in the row direction and they were on the same line. Could anyone give insight. I'm using repl.it IDE for this by the way. I tried to add an image but was telling me error

```
.img{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        float: left;
        background-color: #626B63;
      }
//code for my image.

//code for the image captions
<figure>
    <img src="https://thepienews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Screen-Shot-2017-12-05-at-15.40.31-860x375.png"  width= "200" height="200" style="padding: 3ch;">
 <figcaption>Bookings</figcaption>
    </figure>
<figure>
    <img src= "https://www.debatingeurope.eu/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/degrees.png"  width= "200" height="200" style="padding: 3ch; ">
     <figcaption>Bookings</figcaption>
    </figure>
<figure>
     <img src="https://cdn3.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/62/77/ticket-travel-airline-dollar-money-vector-12556277.jpg" width= "200" height="200" style="padding: 3ch; " >
     <figcaption>Bookings</figcaption>
    </figure>
```

```css
.img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  float: left;
  background-color: #626B63;
}
```

```html
<!-- code for my image. -->

<!-- code for the image captions -->
<figure>
  <img src="https://thepienews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Screen-Shot-2017-12-05-at-15.40.31-860x375.png" width="200" height="200" style="padding: 3ch;">
  <figcaption>Bookings</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="https://www.debatingeurope.eu/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/degrees.png" width="200" height="200" style="padding: 3ch; ">
  <figcaption>Bookings</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="https://cdn3.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/62/77/ticket-travel-airline-dollar-money-vector-12556277.jpg" width="200" height="200" style="padding: 3ch; ">
  <figcaption>Bookings</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I added a parent container with `flex` to align side by side [See more about flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Bcoz, figure tag is a block element, so that takes full width.

And make `margin: 0` for figure tags which have some default margins.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
.container figure {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center
}
.img{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  float: left;
  background-color: #626B63;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<figure>
    <img src="https://thepienews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Screen-Shot-2017-12-05-at-15.40.31-860x375.png"  width= "200" height="200" style="padding: 3ch;">
 <figcaption>Bookings</figcaption>
    </figure>
<figure>
    <img src= "https://thepienews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Screen-Shot-2017-12-05-at-15.40.31-860x375.png"  width= "200" height="200" style="padding: 3ch; ">
     <figcaption>Bookings</figcaption>
    </figure>
<figure>
     <img src="https://thepienews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Screen-Shot-2017-12-05-at-15.40.31-860x375.png" width= "200" height="200" style="padding: 3ch; " >
     <figcaption>Bookings</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: So I tried it out. The last image keeps going under the second one. That is it moves to another line, directly under the second one.

Comment: Not under second one. It should be shown under the first image as my snippet. isn't it? Just run my snippet and check

Comment: Yeah it is on your snippet but not when I run it on my file. I guess there's a bug elsewhere.